# G Sheet - Array Formula - count occurrences value in a list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to convert the formulas below in an array formula in order to count the occurrences of a value in list of items.

Example:

| data | formula | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2) | 1 |
| a | COUNTIF($A$2:$A3,A3) | 2 |
| b | COUNTIF($A$2:$A4,A4) | 1 |
| c | COUNTIF($A$2:$A5,A5) | 1 |
| d | COUNTIF($A$2:$A6,A6) | 1 |
| d | COUNTIF($A$2:$A7,A7) | 2 |

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(each,COUNTIF (A2:each, each)))
```